# Base change for $\sqrt{2}.$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

This is a direct follow-up to [Conjecture on irrational algebraic numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173414/conjecture-on-irrational-algebraic-numbers).

Take the decimal expansion for $\sqrt{2},$ but now think of it as the base $11$ expansion of some number $\theta_{11}.$ Is there an easy (or, failing that, hard) proof that $\theta_{11}$ is transcendental? Of course, same question stands for $\theta_k,$ for your favorite $k>10.$

Comment: $\theta_{11}$ is certainly irrational.  There is a well-known (but still far from proved) conjecture that all algebraic irrationals are normal in all bases.  So (of course) your number *is* transcendental.  But your question (whether there is an easy proof of it) is not answered by this.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar What is the justification for the well-known conjecture?

Comment: Algebraic irrationality "is independent of" base expansions; there are countably many algebraic irrationals; Therefore "with probability 1", all algebraic irrationals are normal to all bases.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Are there reasons to believe in this independency, besides mere numerical observations?

Comment: Since the digits are the same but the base is larger, in a *certain* sense, $\theta_{11}$ has a quicker rational approximations than  $\sqrt 2$. Can this fact affect the irrationality measure of $\theta_{11}$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I cannot actually understand your comment...

Comment: *Of course*, we all believe it is transcendental. And *of course*, we all know that this is way beyond our reach at present. Why ask, then?

Comment: @NikitaSidorov And of course, we all speak for ourselves.

Comment: @NikitaSidorov I, for one, am completely agnostic on the subject, and have absolutely no clue why anyone would believe what you say everyone believes. I am, of course, just a caveman.